# How to deserialize complex JSON with Scala SprayJSON?

Tags: json, scala, parsing

I have the following JSON:

```
{  
   "key1":[  
      {  
         "key2":{  
            "key3":"value3",
            "key4":"value4"
         },
         "key5":{  
            "key6":"value6"
         },
         "key7":[  
            {  
               "key8":"value8",
               "key9":"value9"
            }
         ],
         "key10":"value10",
         "key11":"value11"
      }
   ],
   "key12":"value12"
}
```

How can I retrieve nested elements (e.g. *value6*) using SprayJson.

I managed to only retrieve the top level key *"key1"*.

```
case class Key1(key1: JsArray)
object Key1Protocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val key1: RootJsonFormat[Key1] = jsonFormat1(Key1)
}
<jsonString>.parseJson.convertTo[Key1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help:

```
case class Key1(key1: JsArray)

object Key1Protocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val key1: RootJsonFormat[Key1] = jsonFormat1(Key1)
}

import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

object MainJson {
  import Key1Protocol._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jsonAst = TestComplexJson.str.parseJson.convertTo[Key1]
    val result = jsonAst.key1
      .elements(0)
      .asJsObject
      .getFields("key5")(0)
      .asJsObject()
      .getFields("key6")(0)
    println(result)
  }
}
```

gives "value6"